# Exchange Online and EWS with Basic Auth stopped working

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I want to use EWS managed API with basic authentication to connect to Exchange Online.

But in my application the EWS `AutodiscoverService` is unable to retrive mailbox settings (`GetUserSettings`) from Exchange Online when using basic authentication, but oAuth works just fine.

I get a `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException` with the message "*A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.101.50.162:444*"

I have been using basic auth for several years and a few days ago it just stopped working. Is it no longer possible to use basic authentication with Exchange Online and EWS?

**Code sample**

```
var ads = new AutodiscoverService
             {
                 RedirectionUrlValidationCallback = url => true,
                 EnableScpLookup = false
             };
ads.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( svcUsr, svcPwd ); // using these will throw an exception
ads.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials( token.AccessToken ); // these works
var res = ads.GetUserSettings( mailBox, UserSettingName.GroupingInformation );
```

**The Exception**

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.101.28.194:444
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
       at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverRequest.InternalExecute()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverRequest.InternalExecute()
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.GetUserSettingsRequest.Execute()
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetUserSettings(List`1 smtpAddresses, List`1 settings, Nullable`1 requestedVersion, Uri& autodiscoverUrl)
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetSettings[TGetSettingsResponseCollection,TSettingName](List`1 identities, List`1 settings, Nullable`1 requestedVersion, GetSettingsMethod`2 getSettingsMethod, Func`1 getDomainMethod)
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(List`1 smtpAddresses, List`1 settings)
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetSoapUserSettings(String smtpAddress, List`1 requestedSettings)
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(String userSmtpAddress, UserSettingName[] userSettingNames)
       at EWSAutoDiscovery.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Program.cs:line 57
```

**Things tested and verified [Update 1]**

1. I have verified that some EWS operations still work with basic auth,
   e.g. *SyncFolderItems*.
2. I have verified that the service account user nor the EXO General Config has an Authentication Policy.
3. I have created an Authentication Policy that enables BasicAuth on all protocols and assigned it to the EXO Organization Config DefaultAuthenticationPolicy parameter.
4. I have assigned the Authentication Policy to the service account as well as the target user.
5. I have removed and reapplied the ApplicationImpersonation role on the service account.

Comment: Microsoft are going to be blocking basic auth in the near future (if they aren't already doing so for your tenant): https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-april-2020-update/ba-p/1275508 Now might be the time to investigate changing your application to use Graph API instead?

Comment: MSFT had announced the end of Basic Auth for O365 starting October 2020.  Due to COVID-19 it has been deferred until mid-2021.  However, your Exchange admin can turn this off at any time with a single PowerShell command.

Comment: @pjneary I have updated the post with things tested, I could not find any trace of that BasicAuth was disabled in EXO or that Security Defaults was enabled in the AzureAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autodiscovery with Basic Authentication started to work again during the night, for all O365/Azure tenants using my application.

Microsoft must have fixed something on their side that they broke a few days ago.